# display current month after displaying previous or next month using tapku library in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, events, nscalendar, tapku

I am working on the app. I open the calender using Tapku Library when I click on Event's date (suppose, the date is from next or previous month's date). It will displayed correctly on calendar with this date as selected date, but when I go to the current month, it will display 1st date and current date as a selected date, actually I want to display only current date as a selected date. Can anybody help me.??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using  the

#pragma mark TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate methods**

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {
}
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView monthDidChange:(NSDate *)d {
}
```

Comment: Its done by using - (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)mv monthWillAppear:(NSDate*)month method

Comment: @Radhu willappear and monthDidChange with the same functinolity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17870/discussion-between-radhu-and-vikas-rajput)